# Install PECL_HTTP 1.xx on Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, pear, pecl

Following to PHP.net documentation on [HttpRequest](http://php.net/manual/en/class.httprequest.php) i have written very nice code and want to use it

Then ie found that PECL_HTTP documentation on PHP.net is completely outdated, as PECL_HTTP 2.xx uses completely different concept and classes. I still want to use old version because i like it for now.

The problem is that when i type on my `ubuntu 14 64-bit` server:

```
pecl install pecl_http
```

or

```
pecl install pecl_http-1.7.1
```

I receive common message:

> No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/pecl_http"
>
> install
> failed

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PECL.PHP.NET server was down for many hours, now it's online again. I don't know why `pecl install` was reporting "no release found" instead of "network error", but this was the reason.